# Is it possible to write a Haskell function with type Int -> Float

Tags: haskell

I can write

```
double :: Int -> Float
double i = 2.0
```

but that isn't in any way a function of its argument. Casting is apparently
forbidden, mixed-mode arithmetic isn't supported, so I can't do anything like

```
double :: Int -> Float
double i = 2.0 * i
```

I'm actually trying to figure out how to define

```
series :: (Int -> Float) -> Int -> [Float]
```

to return the infinite series [f(i), f(i+1), f(i+2),...]
but I'm stuck at computing f(i).

If this is really impossible, what type must I use?

Thanks!

Comment: Note the type to `series :: (Integral a, Num b) => (a -> b) -> a -> [b]`, or even `Enum a`, is a more abstract variant that follows (probably) the same implementation.

Comment: Note that you almost certainly want to use `Double`, which is a double-precision floating point number, rather than `Float`, which is single precision and really only intended for special use cases.

Answer (score 9):

I think you're looking for the `fromIntegral` function.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before and didn't get it to work, but now it does. I don't know what I'm doing differently, but now I'm making progress again.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Snoyman's answer is the practical one, but let me show you what you could do if `fromIntegral` didn't exist. First, the super-slow version:

```
intToFloat :: Int -> Float
intToFloat x
  | x > 0 = - itf (- x)
  | otherwise = itf x

-- Convert a negative Int to a Float
itf 0 = 0
itf x = itf (x + 1) - 1
```

This is slow, and may also use a lot of memory. But we can fix it through the power of division! Unfortunately, I can't write it up right now.

Comment: I can see why this would be slow, but I don't see at what point it becomes a Float. When the number gets too large for an Int? But in that case the Float would be wrong.

Comment: Stupid question: is it some kind of type casting which allows you to say 0==0.0 and then increment it till x?